# How to get datetime without Django modifying time?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Django 1.9 / Postgres 9.4 - I have a model datetime field called `date_ending`.  When I get the datetime with `my_item.date_ending` it gives me date and time that is different than what I see when I access the database directly. I set settings.py:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = False
USE_L10N = False
USE_TZ = False
```

This should get django out of changing timezone stuff, correct?  Basically I want Django to not touch timezones at all.  Also, this might be something completey different...

when I save a model with a datetime field and date field.  The date is different thna dthe datetime.

```
datetime_ = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime_date_ = datetime_.date()

MyModel.objects.create(
    datetimefield=datetime_,
    datefield=datetime_date_,
).save()
```

My database:

```
      datetimefield                |      datefield 
 -------------------------------+-----------------
  2016-11-04 18:23:18.407671-07 |        2016-11-05
```

????

Any help please.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it seems to me is that your postgres database is configured to a timezone in UTC-07, so it's storing the date time in that timezone, and when it "subtracts" 7 hours to store the datetime to that timezone, it ends up going back a day. If you change that date time to a UTC (+00) date time, that'd be `2016-11-05 01:23:18.407671+00` or something like that, and it'd correspond with the date field.

If I'm not mistaken, when you retrieve this `datetimefield` using django's ORM, and not directly on the postgre's console, it should convert back to UTC as that is what Django is configured to use.

Comment: Thank you very much.  PostgreSQL 9.4 was set to my dedicated server's time in AZ/US.  I went to my db and typed... `show timezone;` ...to see that it was AZ/US and then changed to UTC by setting it... `set timezone='UTC';`

Comment: @quaerereveritatem :)